# Match strings excluding literal asterisks

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a bunch of fields in a database with ids that are of a form

```
abc::def::123::xyz
```

In some records, one or more parts of the id is replaced by an asterisk, e.g.

```
abc::def::123::xyz
abc::def::*::xyz
abc::def::123::*
```

I am querying a RethinkDB and need to match IDs that do NOT contain an asterisk, but am having trouble getting it working. I've tried:

```
^\*
^[\*]
```

But neither of these work. What am I missing? I'm doing this from Python if that's relevant.

Comment: Use the negative character class `[^*]`

Comment: I don't know this database but obvious candidate would be: `[^*]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But, and correct me if I'm wrong, * is a meta character that would need to be escaped. Correct? Either way, it is still matching ids that contain asterisks.

Comment: Try this one    ^[^*]*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern you may try:

```
^\w{3}(?:::\w{3}){3}$
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

### Demo

If the terms in between `::` could have any length, then use `\w+` to match any number of characters, e.g.

```
^\w+(?:::\w+){3}$
```